# EF query against Database View is very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, entity-framework

I have a simple web application, using MVC and EF4.0. I use VS 2010 and SQL Server 2008 Express installed locally on my workstation.

I have this slow function, I have tried some tricks to speed it up, but with no success. I have had a glance to this links:

[Maximizing Performance with the Entity Framework 4.0 in an ASP.NET Web Application : The Official Microsoft ASP.NET Site](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/continuing-with-ef/maximizing-performance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-web-application)

[Performance Considerations for EF5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

but the amount of information is a little bit overwhelming, for me. That at least, so I need some directions.

```
 public List<VRapportiCT> ViewRapportiToList(string codArticolo, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
 {
        // RapportiEntities : ObjectContext
        RapportiEntities context = new RapportiEntities();

        //context.VRapportiCT.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking; // No improvement

        // startDate = 01/01/2013
        // endDate = 31/12/2013
        List<VRapportiCT> myList = context.VRapportiCT
                        .Where(r => r.DCodArt == codArticolo && r.DStorico >= startDate && r.DStorico <= endDate)
                        .OrderBy(r => r.DStorico).ToList();
        // 1° query Elapsed time: 8 sec.

        myList = context.VRapportiCT
                        .Where(r => r.DCodArt == codArticolo && r.DStorico >= startDate && r.DStorico <= endDate)
                        .OrderBy(r => r.DStorico).ToList();
        // 2° query Elapsed time: 8 sec.

        return myList;
    }
```

The SQL query, executed directly on the DB is very fast, actually less than 0,5 second (I have measured it with SQL Server Profiler).

I use VS 2010 in debug mode to "visually check" the performance (but also compiling the app in Release mode and testing directly the call in the browsers doesn't bring any improvements).

All the time is spent on that `.ToList()` call, but where exactly?

PS. The query returns only a very small number of records, say 10 records, from a view that (unfiltered) contains of course a lot more records ;-)

So the sloppy performance doesn't seem, to me, related to some *"EF magic object's trees materialization and connections behind the scenes"*

**EDIT**
The DB View T-SQL code:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT L.KLinea, LTRIM(RTRIM(L.DLinea)) AS DLinea, LTRIM(RTRIM(R.DCodArt)) AS DCodArt, LTRIM(RTRIM(R.DDescArt)) AS DDescArt, N.KNota, N.DNota,
                       T.DStorico, CAST(DATEPART(day, T.DStorico) AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(month, T.DStorico) AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(year, T.DStorico) AS varchar) 
                      AS Data, REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(U.DTurno)), 'Turno', 'Lettera') AS Lettera, U.KTurno,
FROM         dbo.TRapportiCT AS T INNER JOIN
                      dbo.TPersonale AS P ON T.KPersona = P.KPersona INNER JOIN
                      dbo.TTurni AS U ON T.KTurno = U.KTurno INNER JOIN
                      dbo.RRapNotCod AS R ON T.KRapporto = R.KRapporto INNER JOIN
                      dbo.TLinea AS L ON R.KLinea = L.KLinea INNER JOIN
                      dbo.TNoteCT AS N ON R.KNota = N.KNota
WHERE     (P.KRuolo = 2)
ORDER BY T.DStorico, N.KOrdine
```

The unfiltered View returns 54.000 records.

Comment: Can you add the code for VRapportiCT and indicate if you have disabled Lazy Loading?
You can also check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework) to see how to get the real query that is being executed

Comment: @Sebastian I see the real query string from SQL profiler, and it's ok

Comment: @Sebastian I don't know how to disable lazy loading :-(

Comment: @Sebastian VRapportiCT is a db view, that I have imported manually inside the .edmx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, stop whining.

I have exported the code on the production server and tested against SQL Server 2005.

No delay anymore, the query gets executed almost instantly.

So, after all, this issue seems only related to my local **SQL Server 2008 Express**. (what's an annoying problem)