# Entity Framework and SQL Server Express bottlenecks

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, sql-server-express

I have stumbled upon this **slow performace problem** using my local installed SQL Server 2008 Express.
(For complete background see my other SO post: [EF query against Database View is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142049/ef-query-against-database-view-is-very-slow/20143074#20143074))

Instead, when I use SQL Server 2005 as the backend, I have no issues at all.

So, my question is: what is the problem between EF4.0 and SQL Server Express?

Comment: Well, the free Express edition is quite limited: it can only ever use max. of 1 GB of RAM and 1 CPU - no matter how much your machine has. So things **will** be slower than on a "full" version of SQL Server. It's not an Entity Framework problem (I would guess) - it's limitations of SQL Server **Express** that you're experiencing, I think

Comment: in addition to marc_s good suggestion. it might App pool recycling causing the model to load each time... See the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327(v=vs.110).aspx  it could be one of many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Below are some of the things that should be kept in mind while designing your sql queries.

- Poor Indexing
- Poor Statistics